# How to install rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I've installed ruby2.0 and made it the default:

```
rabdelaz@q2-apps-gss01:~$ ruby -v 
ruby 2.0.0p384 (2014-01-12) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

rabdelaz@q2-apps-gss01:~$ sudo ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p384 (2014-01-12) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

But when I go to install rails I still get the following:

```
rabdelaz@q2-apps-gss01:~$ sudo gem install rails
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    i18n requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

My ubuntu version:

```
rabdelaz@q2-apps-gss01:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: What does `sudo ruby -v` say?

Comment: Same thing - updated my question.

Comment: While I don't know what's wrong in this case, I can recommend 1) using a newer ruby (2.5.1 is the current one, I think) and 2) using a ruby version manager (I prefer chruby/ruby-install, but there's also RVM, rbenv and maybe others)

Comment: Never use `sudo` to install gems. It's not a good idea to install gems as `root`, try installing `gem install rails --verbose` and see if it succeeds or fails. If it fails update your question with the output.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like installing everything via RVM is the easiest way to go: `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails` (ref: https://rvm.io/rvm/install)